# Emacs for Windows freezes sometime on Windows xp

Tags: emacsw32

I have tried two version of emacs for windows (i.e GNU Emacs for Windows, and EmacsWin32). Both have the same problem. When I enter text or save the file, they sometime freeze for 5~6 seconds and then they come back.

Is there a specific setting I have to do in order to fix this problems?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this, too. For me, this happens only under Emacs 23, though. So, while not a real solution, as a workaround, you might consider using Emacs 22 under XP instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check your performance. Sounds like your are running out of memory so it is paging to disk. Use a leaner emacs setup maybe? Or add memory, or free up some by stopping other programs and services.

Comment: I don't have any of the above issues.